# @ActiveProfiles value is not being assigned to config

Tags: spring, jpa

My Active profiles are working normally if I set them as VM args.

I've got a test with which I want to use `@ActiveProfiles("local")`.

Here are the class annotation's I'm using:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("/jpaContext.xml")
@ActiveProfiles("local")
public class MyServiceTest {
```

When I try to run I get the following in my trace:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [properties/database-configuration-${spring.profiles.active}.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

Any thoughts on why this value is not being used?

Answer (score 5):

When you are resolving the placeholder value of `spring.profiles.active` in your configuration file, Spring is defaulting to the system properties for the value and gets the value when you set it as a system property.

Now, in your test, since this system property is not being set, the placeholder is not getting cleanly resolved. One fix could to load the properties a little differently, through bean profiles:

```
<beans profile="local">
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:database-config-local.properties"/>
</beans>

<beans profile="dev">
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:database-config-dev.properties"/>
</beans>
```

Comment: The problem is that the `@ActiveProfiles` annotation does not set the `spring.profiles.active` property in the `Environment` (it just sets the active profiles, which is different). If you don't want to change your config like suggested, you could add an `ApplicationContextInitializer` to the test (in the `@ContextConfiguration`) that adds a property source with the active profile key.