# Defining a spring active profile within a test use case

Tags: java, spring, spring-test

Using Spring 4, I've got the following test setup:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = JpaConfig.class)
@ActiveProfiles(resolver = TestResolver.class)
public class SimpleTest {
```

The TestResolver has been implemented as:

```
public class TestResolver implements ActiveProfilesResolver {
    @Override
    public String[] resolve(Class<?> aClass) {
        String[] profiles = new String[1];
        profiles[0] = "test";
        return profiles;
    }
}
```

JpaConfig has been annotated with PropertySource

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:properties/application-${spring.profiles.active:dev}.properties")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages={"com.my.namespace.repositories"})
public class JpaConfig {
```

Whenever I run the SimpleTest it tries to locate: properties/application-dev.properties while I expected it to be properties/application-test.properties.

What's I'm trying to accomplish here has been based on the following post: [Spring integration tests with profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20551681/spring-integration-tests-with-profile)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22053683/activeprofiles-value-is-not-being-assigned-to-config) is, actually, the issue you are facing. And in that [same post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22053683/activeprofiles-value-is-not-being-assigned-to-config) you have an explanation from Dave Syer and a possible solution from another user. To follow Dave's advice, this would be a possible implementation of an `ApplicationContextInitializer`:

```
public class MyApplicationContextInitializer implements
    ApplicationContextInitializer<GenericApplicationContext> {

public void initialize(GenericApplicationContext context) {
    context.getEnvironment().getSystemProperties().put(AbstractEnvironment.ACTIVE_PROFILES_PROPERTY_NAME, "some_profile");
}
```

}

and on your test class:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = JpaConfig.class, initializers = MyApplicationContextInitializer.class)
```

But I would say that the suggested approach (with different .properties files loaded for different profiles) in that SO post is a more elegant approach.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should change @PropertySource to:

```
@PropertySource("classpath:properties/application-${spring.profiles.active}.properties")
```

Also for simplicity (shouldn't have any effect on how the code runs) your @ActiveProfile could be

```
@ActiveProfiles("test")
```

Comment: When I do this I get: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'spring.profiles.active' in string value "classpath:properties/application-${spring.profiles.active}.properties"

Comment: How about if you swap the position of @ActiveProfile and @ContextConfiguration?

Comment: Doesn't change anything

Comment: Seems strange that it doesn't work... Do you have the code in GitHub or something to share?

Comment: Are there any news on the subject of 'spring.profiles.active' not being resolved ? Cause I face the very same issue and am stuck loosing points of sanity :(